# Collapsing toolbar title gravity does not set to bottom

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

i am using collapsing toolbar with toolbar only here my purpose 
is to use default parallex feature for toolbar,but the problem i am facing that back arrow and title in expanded form overlapping each other i tried to set expandedtitlegravity to bottom didn't work either

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/SavedCollapsedAppBar"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="20dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
             app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/SavedExpandedAppBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:theme="@style/SavedToolbarColoredBackArrow"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
                    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/SavedCollapsedAppBar"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/black" />
           </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

         </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's seems like, the problem is with the `Toolbar`.

set `app:contentInsetStart` in `Toolbar` i.e.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          ...
          app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
```

It may solve the problem.

Comment: resolved the issue android:fitsSystemWindows="true" works for me ,